# Make a wxPanel resizable by the user

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a wxPanel. How can I make it resizable by the user? With a drag-and-drop resize bar?

I wonder what the widgets I need are.

Thank you.

Comment: i think you want a splitter ... take a look in the wxDemo they have a nice example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `wx.SplitterWindow` to make panels in a frame to be resizable (that is to divide a frame in, for example, two resizable sub-windows).

If what you want is to be able to resize a panel on a grid of other panels then you can use `wx.lib.resizewidget`. This provides of a drag-and-drop like bar but you can not move the position of the widget only resize it.

You have examples of both in the [wxpython docs and demos package](http://www.wxpython.org/download.php#stable)

Here you have an example using a SplitterWindow (the code is very verbose because was autogenerated with wxglade. It can be simplified if you want to):

```
import wx  

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.window_1 = wx.SplitterWindow(self, wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.SP_3D | wx.SP_BORDER)
        self.window_1_pane_1 = wx.Panel(self.window_1, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.window_1_pane_2 = wx.Panel(self.window_1, wx.ID_ANY)

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()

    def __set_properties(self):
        self.SetTitle("frame_1")
        self.window_1_pane_1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(255, 255, 0))
        self.window_1_pane_2.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(50, 153, 204))

    def __do_layout(self):
        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.window_1.SplitVertically(self.window_1_pane_1, self.window_1_pane_2)
        sizer_1.Add(self.window_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
        sizer_1.Fit(self)
        self.Layout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
    wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
    frame_1 = MyFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
    app.SetTopWindow(frame_1)
    frame_1.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A Panel floating all by itself?  Doesn't sound too likely!  It would be a lot easier to answer this question if you described in more detail what you are doing, and what is not working as you expect.

In general, panels are created as children of a frame.  If the panel is the ONLY child of the frame, then it will be resized automatically along with the frame.  Otherwise you will have to handle the resize event yourself.

What have you tried so far?

Comment: @user996056 Please edit your question so we can understand what you want to do. 'I have a wxPanel' is wrong and misleading. It would also help to describe what you have tried so far.